# How can I force Scrutinizer to scan .inc files

Tags: php, continuous-integration, scrutinizer

It seems Scrutinizer does not find or detect the .inc files as PHP although they are PHP files but need this extension.

Is there some setting for the YAML-file to treat the .inc files as PHP files and actually detect them, and can I rename *.inc to *.php for Scrutinizer without changing the files in the repository?

It seems this is hardcoded to *.php

https://github.com/scrutinizer-ci/php-analyzer/blob/36a82213e272d5b6a158d223b9e35358e348c112/src/Scrutinizer/PhpAnalyzer/Command/RunCommand.php#L56